# Перемещение точки на карте на определенное расстояние в метрах

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, yandex-maps-api

Есть несколько точек. Все эти точки требуется переместить на 30 метров от первоначального положения.
Мысль, которая есть у меня - перевести эти 30 метров в градусы и задать новое значение точки. Расстояние в 1 градусе, если я не ошибаюсь, около 111 км. Но результат перемещения скорее всего будет очень не точным.
Есть ли какие-нибудь функции для упрощения этой задачи?

Comment: Проблема в том, что нельзя взаимооднозначно поставить градусам метры. На уровне экватора -- это одно расстояние. На уровне Москвы -- другое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Апи Яндекс карт есть специальный метод для этого, в документации ниже есть пример : https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ICoordSystem-docpage/#method_detail__solveDirectProblem

```
// Начальная точка 
var startPoint = [60, 30],
// Движемся на северо-восток, азимут 45 градусов
// или pi/4 радиан.
azimuth = Math.PI / 4,
// Направление движения.
direction = [Math.cos(azimuth), Math.sin(azimuth)],
 // Путевая функция
 path = ymaps.coordSystem.geo
 .solveDirectProblem(startPoint, direction, 2e5).pathFunction;
```

Answer (score 1):

При движении по меридиану изменится широта на `30/111111` градуса, при движении по параллели на широте φ изменится долгота на `30/111111/(cos φ)`

Для общего случая при движении по произвольному азимуту можно воспользоваться формулами [отсюда](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) (раздел `Destination point given distance and bearing from start point` )

```
Formula:
φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )
λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )

where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, θ is the bearing (clockwise from north), δ is the angular distance d/R; d being the distance travelled, R the earth’s radius

JavaScript:
(all angles in radians)
var φ2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(d/R) +
                    Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
var λ2 = λ1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(φ1),
                         Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Считать лучше непосредственно через Яндекс. Если Вы получаете координаты от него, если для Вас критично получить точные значения. Это связано с тем, что координаты могут отличаться, в зависимости от того, какие проекции использует Яндекс при геокодировании.

YandexMaps Api обладает 3мя возможностями посчитать расстояние между точками:

- Во фронте
- На бэке
- Через маршруты.

Во фронте:

```
ymaps.route(['Минск','Москва']);
```

В бекенде:

Если координат нет, то их можно получить через геокодер:

```
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=Москва&format=json
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=Минск&format=json
```

Считаем расстояние:

```
https://api.routing.yandex.net/v1.0.0/distancematrix?origins=55.753215,37.622504&destinations=27.561481,53.902496&mode=driving&apikey={{ваш ключ}}
```

Но есть одно "Но". В итоге мы можем получить разные дистанции. Чтобы этого избежать следует использовать [API Маршрутизатора](https://tech.yandex.ru/routing/router/#start?from=SO). Этот API возвращает сразу и геометрию маршрута (полилинию), которую можно отобразить на карте. Но здесь следует учитывать тот факт, что

Comment: Вторая точка неизвестна

Comment: Тогда, действительно, лучше воспользоваться тем решнием, которое предложил участник выше, чтобы не костылять.